# How do deploy aggregated javadocs to github

Tags: maven, github

I am using the github site-maven-plugin to deploy my site docs:

https://github.com/github/maven-plugins

But I have a multi-module project and it seems to just deploy only individual modules, not the whole aggregated site. How can I deploy the aggregated site docs?

Here is my maven plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <author>true</author>
                <bottom>true</bottom>
                <destDir>javadoc</destDir>
                <!-- <header><![CDATA[<a href="/" target="_top">Spring Utility</a>]]></header> -->
                <header><![CDATA[<a href="/" target="_top">${project.description}</a>]]></header>
                <minmemory>128m</minmemory>
                <maxmemory>512</maxmemory>
                <overview>${site.basedir}/src/main/javadoc/overview.html</overview>
                <packagenames>com.baselogic.*</packagenames>
                <use>true</use>
                <version>true</version>
                <windowtitle>${project.name} ${project.version} API</windowtitle>
                <doclet>ydoc.doclets.YStandard</doclet>
                <docletPath>${site.basedir}/src/yworks/ydoc.jar;${site.basedir}/src/yworks/styleed.jar;${site.basedir}/src/yworks/resources;${build.classes.dir};</docletPath>
                <additionalparam>-umlautogen -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/</additionalparam>
                <tag name="noinspection" description="IntelliJ Inspection Ignore tag"
                    enabled="false" />

                <doctitle>API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle> <!-- Used by javadoc:javadoc goal -->
                <windowtitle>API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</windowtitle> <!-- Used by javadoc:javadoc goal -->

                <testDoctitle>Test API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</testDoctitle> <!-- Used by javadoc:test-javadoc goal -->
                <testWindowtitle>Test API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</testWindowtitle> <!-- Used by javadoc:test-javadoc goal -->                

            </configuration>

            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>html</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <doctitle>API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</doctitle>
                        <windowtitle>API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</windowtitle>
                    </configuration>
                    <reports>
                        <report>aggregate</report>
                        <!-- <report>javadoc</report>
                        <report>test-javadoc</report> -->
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
                <reportSet>
                    <id>test-html</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <testDoctitle>Test API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</testDoctitle>
                        <testWindowtitle>Test API for ${project.name} ${project.version}</testWindowtitle>
                    </configuration>
                    <reports>
                        <report>aggregate</report>
                        <!-- <report>test-javadoc</report> -->
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>                  

        </plugin>
```

The site on my own server looks fine:
http://baselogic.com/code/SpringCertification/

But the Github is still just the last module:
http://mickknutson.github.com/SpringCertification/

Comment: Have you run a complete mvn site fro mthe root of your multi-module build and done a mvn site:deploy ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [aggregate goal of the javadoc plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate.html) and bind it to the 'site' phase.  Then whatever is posting to github should include all submodules